# Generic and non-generic interfaces

Tags: c#, generics

I come across a lot of situations where I have declared a generic interface and later I needed a non-generic version of this interface, or at least non-generic version of some of the methods or properties on that interface. 
  I would usually declare a new non-generic interface and have it inherit the generic interface.
  The problem I am running into in shows in the example below:

```
public abstract class FormatBase { }

public interface IBook<F> where F : FormatBase
{
    F GetFormat();
}

public interface IBook
{
    object GetFormat();
}

public abstract class BookBase : IBook<FormatBase>, IBook
{
    public abstract FormatBase GetFormat();

    object IBook.GetFormat()
    {
        return GetFormat();
    }
}
```

Since the only way to declare the IBook (non-generic) interface is explicitly, how do you guys go about making it abstract?

Comment: This doesn't fix your problem, but don't you think it might make sense to make it `BookBase<T> : IBook<T>, IBook where T : FormatBase`?  Otherwise, in your simple example at least, there's little to no benefit having `IBook<T>` instead of just `IBook`.

Comment: You are right. I updates the code. But the issue with the non generic abstract still exists.

Comment: You will also get a "'IBook<F>.GetFormat()' hides inherited member 'IBook.GetFormat()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended." warning. This is probably due to a poor design decision somewhere but without more information it is hard to say what a better design would be.

Comment: Not related to your question, but maybe you want to make the generic interface covariant in `F`, saying `public interface IBook<out F>`?

Comment: I made one more change to remove "Use new keyword..." message. IBook<F> does not inherit from IBook anymore. Thanks guys

Comment: @user1171461: I'd still think `IBook` and `IBook<F>` should be related...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you can't write implementation of explicit interface, instead of declaring it abstract?

```
public abstract class BookBase : IBook<FormatBase>, IBook
{                
    public abstract FormatBase GetFormat();

    object IBook.GetFormat()
    {
        return GetFormat();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jordão release the trigger :)

Comment: @spender this line forces inheritors of BookBase to write their implementations of GetFormat

Comment: @spender I propose to add `GetFormat` implementation. That's the idea :)

Comment: Aww crap. I'm having a bad day. Ignore me.

Answer (score 7):

Just delegate:

```
public abstract class BookBase : IBook<FormatBase> {
  public abstract FormatBase GetFormat();

  object IBook.GetFormat() {
    return GetFormat();
  }
}
```

Or, if you still want to differentiate both methods, delegate to a new method:

```
public abstract class BookBase : IBook<FormatBase> {
  public abstract FormatBase GetFormat();

  public abstract object IBook_GetFormat();

  object IBook.GetFormat() {
    return IBook_GetFormat();
  }
}
```

You also need `new` to dodge a "hiding inherited member" warning:

```
public interface IBook<F> : IBook 
where F : FormatBase {
  new F GetFormat();
}
```

Also, it might make more sense to let concrete classes decide on the concrete `FormatBase`:

```
public abstract class BookBase<F> : IBook<F> 
where F : FormatBase {
  public abstract F GetFormat();

  object IBook.GetFormat() {
    return GetFormat();
  }
}
```

Comment: @spender, I don't see a better way to do it, do you?

Comment: @spender: use `new` or change the name... Since the OP wants the same name, either he uses `new` or gets a warning.... I don't know about you, but I don't like being warned about _intentional_ decisions I've made...

Comment: Compare this with .NET's own interface `IEnumerable<T>` which derives from `IEnumerable`. It also has this method signature conflict (signatures agree, return types do not). Do they have this warning when they compile mscorlib, or do they say `new`?

Comment: The warning if clear: "use the `new` keyword if hiding was intended". As hiding is intended, the usage of `new` is fine.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Since it was an _intentional_ decision, I'd bet my horse (if I had one) they use `new`...